# Can't use input type text from iframe iPad iOS 8 Safari

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, safari, ios8

currently I am facing the following problem:
I have a page with an iframe, it loads a page with a form.
The site runs on all browsers with no error message.
But in Safari under iOS8 on the iPad, there is a problem.
(only on the iPad iOS8, on iPhone and iPad iOS7 it works)
When I select an input field of type text and try to write the complete page is reloaded.
With the error message "The website has been reloaded, because there was a problem."

iframe:

```
<iframe src="[TargetSite]" id="frame" scrolling="no" name="iframebox" seamless="seamless" ></iframe>
```

form:

```
<form action="[TargetSite]" method="post">
  <input name="ctextBoxPsasword" type="password" id="textBoxPsasword" tabindex="2" class="tBoxLogin floatR" />
  <input name="textBoxUserName" type="text" id="textBoxUserName" tabindex="1" class="tBoxLogin" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not solved the problem, but I have found the reason and so for me it is no longer a problem.
The combination of the page and the page loaded in the iframe is too large for the iPads Safari.
If you go to the text field inside the iframe and thus calls the screen keyboard, the maximum memory for Safari is exceeded therefore the application reload the page.